# decode the result from google in Python

Tags: python, search, encode

I tried to make programme to get urls from google

but the problem is i got encoded urls ! like this !

```
`[u'http://www.motorrad-live.de/test.php%3Fid%3D11', u'http://www.autogaleria.pl/
auto_test/test.php%3Fid%3D37', u'http://oculus.ru/test.php%3Fid%3D2', u'http://o
culus.ru/test.php%3Fid%3D1', u'http://www.kerrytaylorauctions.com/detail-test.ph
p%3Fid%3D3432', u'http://radio.ghanaweb.com/live-radio.test.php?id=3D4', u'http:
//www.studygerman.ru/test/test.php%3Fid%3D261', u'http://www.mhealth.ru/tests/te
st.php%3Fid%3D300']
```

as you see after `.php` there something encoded !

here is my code even thoug my code content part to decode !!

```
import json
import urllib


def print_results(results):
    mylist=[]
    n=[]
    for r in results:
        mylist.append(r['url'])
    for each in mylist:
         n.append(each.replace(u"%3FID%","?id="))
    print n


def query(qs):
    f = urllib.urlopen('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&gl=de&q=%s&rsz=8&start=7'%qs)
    s = f.read()
    j = json.loads(s)

    return j['responseData']['results']
a=query('inurl:"test.php?id"')
print_results(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're searching for the function unquote:

```
urllib.unquote(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

first you need to quote the query string before interpolating it:

```
>>> urllib.quote("inurl:\"test.php?id\"")
'inurl%3A%22test.php%3Fid%22'

>>> "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&gl=de&q=%(q)s&rsz=8&start=0" % dict(q=urllib.quote("inurl:\"test.php?id\""))
'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&gl=de&q=inurl%3A%22test.php%3Fid%22&rsz=8&start=0'
```

second i looked at the returned json and saw that the unencoded url is stored under the key `unescapedUrl` so you can replace `print_results(results)` with:

```
def print_results(results):
    L=list(r['unescapedUrl'] for r in results)
    print L
```

if you really need to read it from the `url` key, use:

```
def print_results(results):
    L=list(urllib.unquote(r['url']) for r in results)
    print L
```

Comment: note that http://jsbeautifier.org/ was quite useful in reformating the returned json.